# Angular scope watch doesn't work in my app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I've got the following code where I'm trying to show/hide a text box based on if a key was pressed in the global window scope. However, every time a key is pressed, it does not seem to fire the watch service. Why is this?

Plnkr here http://plnkr.co/edit/qL9ShNKegqJfnyMvichk

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $window) {
 $scope.name = '';


angular.element($window).on('keypress', function(e) {
//this changes the name variable 
$scope.name = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
 console.log($scope.name)
})


$scope.$watch('name', function() {
 console.log('hey, name has changed!');
 });
});
```

Comment: ```$watch``` seems to be firing and logging to the console just fine. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are handling the `keypress` event outside of the digest cycle. I would strongly encourage you to let angular do its thing with databinding or using  [`ngKeypress`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeypress)

Otherwise, in your handler, call `$scope.$digest()`.

```
angular.element($window).on('keypress', function(e) {
    //this changes the name variable 
    $scope.name = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    console.log($scope.name);
    $scope.$digest();
})
```

Comment: Daniel, how do you recommend I do this- staying inside the digest cycle?

Comment: @user1142130 i'm not sure what you are hoping to accomplish. perhaps expanding why you are listening to all keypresses in a controller.

Answer (score 0):

On a high level view, watching a value on a scope needs two parts:

First: the watcher - like you created one. Every watcher has two parts, the watch function (or like here the value) and the listener function. The watch function returns the watched object, the listener function is called when the object has changed.

Second: the $digest cycle. The $digest loops over all watchers on a scope, calls the watch function, compares the returned newValue with the oldValue and calls the corresponding listener function if these two do not match. This is called dirty-checking.

But someone has to kick the $digest. Angular does it inside its directives for you, so you don't care. Also all build-in services start the digest. But if you change the object outside of angular's control you have to call $digest yourself, or the preferred way, use $apply.

```
$scope.$apply(function(newName) {
$scope.name = newName;
```

});

$apply first evaluates the function and then starts the $digest.

In your special case, I would suggest to use ngKeypress to do it the angular way.